# React Native - Have view height set by content

Tags: react-native, flexbox

I have a view and a scroll view that currently take up the full height due to the flex: 1 property. I'm trying to figure out how the have this view only take up the amount of space that the content within the scroll view takes up. Is this possible?

```
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>      
  <ScrollView style={{ flexDirection: 'row', flex: 1 }}>...</ScrollView>
</View>
```

Answer (score 7):

Setting `style={{ height: 'auto', flex: 0 }}` on both View and ScrollView worked.

Comment: RN don't have height: 'auto'

Comment: Then either one of two things happened here. 1) The `height` attribute was completely ignored and this would have worked with only `flex: 0`, or 2) Setting the invalid height attribute triggered some fallback height to be set making it accidentally work the way I wanted it to.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to te Text component:

```
flexShrink: 1
```

Also you may need

```
flexWrap: "wrap"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `height: "auto", alignSelf: 'flex-start'`

Answer (score -2):

Remove flex 1 from View, then if you set the height of ScrollView to 500 the View will be 500 as well.

Comment: I am looking for a way for the height to be set based on the content within, not having to explicitly set the height.